# PHP SQL: Find smallest value using PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am attempting to find the smallest value in my SQL records using a PDO connection.  The records are varchar so must be converted to int in order to find smallest.  I am stuck on this issue:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given
```

The problem is I do not know how to get a resource from a PDO connection.  The query is valid.

```
<?php

//load and connect
require("config.inc.php");

        //change varcar to ints and put into array
        $query = "SELECT score FROM easy";
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $scoreArray = array();

        $index = 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
             $scoreArray[$index] = intval($row);
             $index++;
        }
        $smallest = min($scoreArray);

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "The min is: ".$smallest;
        echo(json_encode($response));

?>
```

Comment: You need to use not PDO but **SQL**. Because it is what SQL exactly for

Comment: **mysql_fetch_assoc** is related to the old depreciated **mysql** function. It has nothing to do with **PDO**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to convert your field to int.
2. find smallest value by means of SQL:

   ```
   SELECT min(score) FROM easy
   ```

While selecting all the records from database and process them in PHP is **NOT the way to go.** It's against the very basic principles. Data mining is a job for database.

```
    $query = "SELECT min(score) FROM easy";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $min    = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: I cannot change the field to int because I am posting the score from an Android request and will only allow my to post varchar

Comment: Oh surely you can. Android has nothing to do with that

Comment: Can I post the data as an int?  I read from another answer you can only post varchars

Comment: @Shane "[MIN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the minimum string value." And if your column type is `int`, then when inserting mysql will cast appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `mysql_fetch_assoc` when using PDO:

Replace

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
```

with

```
foreach ( $rows as $row ){
```

Comment: Sorry, why am i being marked down? My answer resolves the error being thrown as illustrated in the question, albeit it doesn't answer the title (which are often misleading anyways). Quote: "The problem is I do not know how to get a resource from a PDO connection."